# How to set a background color for each word in an input tag, but not for spaces

Tags: html, css

If I had text in a p tag, I could wrap each word I want to be highlighted in a span. My issue is that I'm trying to highlight each word from an input tag, but I don't want spaces to also have a background color. How can I solve this?

Comment: I suggest you to use a div and copy value of input instead of use input itself, because you can't style input like your request

Comment: Okay, I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution than that, but I wasn't sure if this was even possible.

Comment: No matter which option you go with, there's going to be javascript involved. It's possible to use a linear-gradient background with a filter: drop-shadow combined with some fancy math based on the width of the words, but it really is much cleaner / easier to do as Simone suggested.

Comment: If you put some more detail about the specific use case you have, what is it you're trying to do, that might be helpful on suggesting a more elegant alternative.

Comment: I'm trying to have a user's input text have a background color for each word in the input. The input text will be used as tags, so that's why I need spaces to be transparent. As the user types their tags, each tag should be highlighted, in this case, tags are space-separated.

Comment: You need to use or create a tag control where each bit of text is an "object". Kendo has this, as an example: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index. Whatever you do make your control accessible/a11y compliant.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be happy if someone says otherwise, but I do not believe what you are asking to do is possible with HTML / CSS only.

Comment: is this the answer? put comments where they belong.

Comment: Do you know what technology I should look into to make this possible?

Comment: @marzelin please correct me if I'm wrong, but if the question is "How do I..." and the answer is "You can't" then... that's an answer, isn't it?

Comment: @Kevon Am I not supposed to ask further questions here?

Comment: @Aeton you're fine. I was asking for clarification from the other guy :)

Comment: @Kevon it an answer that doesn't solve the problem, you're just admitting that you don't know the answer. Thank you for sharing but you should put it in the comments if at all.